# Problem Setting up Drupal Site as OAuth Server

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I've been going through [OAuth2 Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_server) module setup Documentation/Guidelines for almost 2 days now, and also referred with friend who has this working. But unable to get this working properly.

I've a Drupal 7 Site already in use for quite some time (3-4 years). We're building few more applications (in other PHP Framework - not using Drupal), where we want to use/share users from this existing D7 site. To achieve this, we're making existing D7 site as Authentication Server by implementing [OAuth2 Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth2_server) module and [OpenID Connect Single Sign-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect_sso) module. I've configured it as per documentation provided on [OAuth2 Server](https://www.drupal.org/node/1938218) Page.

As a Test client to quickly setup and test, I've setup Another fresh D7 setup and configured [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) Module and [OpenID Connect Single Sign-on](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect_sso) module.

Both these Server and Clients are setup/configured using the Steps provided on [OpenID Connect Single Sign-on Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274367) and also includes **HTTPS** in URL (self-signed).

---

**Problem:**

1. Now when trying to login on Client using "**Log in with Generic**" button provided by [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) Module, the authentication takes me to Server for login where I put my login details and it takes me back to Client. At this stage I'm logged into Server but not on client.
   When debug more about this I found that in client, I receive below log in Recent Logs:

> **Location :**
>   https://client.local.com/openid-connect/generic?code=026ebfd35389b9e3a667a03eb778cdab4d3cc3e4&state=iNaaCcI4pxxZXssUAIO9gdz2Nm8zG5RbhsQ25azigYw
>
> **Message :** Could not retrieve tokens (0 Error opening socket
>   ssl://server.local.com:443). Details:

2. Now, if I go to Client [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) Module's configuration and change the **3 Endpoints** URLs from **https** to **http** and try to login and follow the steps, I'm able to login. (Note: Server is using **http** and client is using **https** - In this case, it asks to login 2 times, one on http and another on https).
3. Another problem I'm facing after #2 is, when I'm trying to login/logout from client site, it takes me to server or vice versa and only one (either server/client) shows latest updates about login/logout, where I've triggered the event.

---

**Other information:**

**OS:** currently Windows 8 with XAMPP (production uses CentOS)
**Drupal Version:** 7.52/7.53
**PHP Version:** 7.0.3

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

### Edit 1:

1. Added debug info for #1.
2. I've also tried configuring another clean Drupal installation as OAuth2 Server, but in that also I'm facing similar issue.

---

### Edit 2:

After some more research found this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2761345), which mentions that

> The behavior of drupal_http_request() changes, because PHP 7 has
>   changed the defaults regarding the ssl options.
>
> This makes code fail that relies on issuing a http request to a https
>   version of a site, which uses a self-signed certificate.

After applying changes in issue for `'context'`, Problem 1 and 2 seems to be fixed. i.e. User is getting logged in both Sites, and authorization is working with *https* enabled endpoint URL as well.

But Problem 3 remains there, i.e. when user try to login in client it take user to server for authorization and stays in server only. User is not re-directed back to client.